# Is there a way to get notified when a UWP is uninstalled?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I'm developing a UWP app and I'd like to know if there is a way to get notified as soon as a user uninstall my app.

Is there something like a "uninstalled" notification callback through Azure WNS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, nothing like this. Your bets bet would be integrate some kind of analytics service and compare active users to installs.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the uninstall event:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.PackageCatalog.PackageUninstalling
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.packagecatalog.packageuninstalling